# ok to run PVC pipe behind gas meter?

Tags: code-compliance, gas, pvc, meter

I am considering installing a radon mitigation pipe system in my home, but the only area where I could reasonably have the pipe exit my home is crammed with all my other utilities.

The best spot I've found that I can conceivably would exit the house very close to my gas meter.  It won't interfere or touch, but I wonder if I would violate some housing code or another.

I'm aware that local codes always vary, but surely there must be some generalized consistency between them, so I hope someone can comment based on their own knowledge and experience.

The attached pictures show the area where the pipe would exit.  I plan on using 2" PVC pipe in the immediate vicinity of the exit, then expanding to 3" pipe for the rest of the vertical run up to the roofline.  Imagine a 2" PVC pipe running about 12" to the left of and more or less parallel to the black gas line seen exiting the meter and entering the house.

Note that this pipe would not "vent" near the gas meter - the vent would be located 2 stories up, above the roof line.  Also, the pipe will only carry air from underneath the house, no gas or fumes, so I don't think that [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/84260/venting-by-gas-meter) applies.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you exit a few feet higher to stay out of the way of meter maintenance?  Run the 2 inch pipe up inside the wall from the basement to about 5 feet above ground?  I don't know anything about radon are you allowed to use flexible pipe for that part of the run?  That would make it easier.

Answer (score 1):

Going along side to the right won’t be a problem, on the left the gas co could be “pissy” because that is the supply but the right is your responsibility. There is no power and no classified flammable or combustibles being pushed through the pipe so you should not have a problem with the vent on the right side of the meter.

Comment: Thanks, Ed.  Unfortunately, there is no space on the interior of the house to put a pipe on the right.

Comment: They may not like it on the left, since you need to use the left side I would set it up so you could remove the pipe if they needed to do meter or regulator work. Abatement systems are low pressure and since this is outside I might not glue that section together so it could be pulled apart if the gas company needed to do work without cutting the pipe.